# Iterating an object and fetching all the keys and setting them to a new field in aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an object where I have a key whose value is an object. I would like to add a new field into a document which contains the name of all the keys.

Sample object:

```
{
   heros: {
       superman: 51,
       batman: 89,
       ironman: 95,
   }
}
```

Expected output after doing a `$addField`:

```
{
   heros: {
       superman: 51,
       batman: 89,
       ironman: 95,
   }
   allHeros: ['superman', 'batman', 'ironman'],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$objectToArray` convert `heros` object to array key-value format
- `$map` to iterate loop of above converted array and return key

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      allHeros: {
        $map: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$heros" },
          in: "$$this.k"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/07JVtpNN8QA)

---

There is second option as well,

- `$objectToArray` convert `heros` object to array key-value format
- just use `allHeros.k` and it will return array of keys

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      allHeros: { $objectToArray: "$heros" }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      allHeros: "$allHeros.k"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M-K3MiQJ5_k)

Comment: What's this .k at the end inside map? Does that mean referring to the keys of the same object?

Comment: yes $objectToArray, will generate array format from object key to `k` and value to `v`, so it will result in key-value format array of object.